# How check on button tapped GPS is Enabled Or Not in swift(ios)? if yes then start map otherwise go to gps menu

Tags: ios, swift

please give a code for this.how to check GPS is enabled or disabled at particular tapped event .

Comment: What have you tried so far? what problems are you getting? Have you tried using Google?

Comment: yes already used google god. but can not got appropriate solution,

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code -

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    {
      // Load Map
    }
    else
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function 
`CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()`
This returns an enum

> typedef enum {    kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
>   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,    kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
>   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized, } CLAuthorizationStatus;

More help on [Apple Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/CLAuthorizationStatus)